# Recaptcha v2 verification expires while uploading big files

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a file upload form and a user is allowed to upload even big files ~200MB.
I am using Google Recaptcha v2. A user is required to click on captcha's checkbox before clicking on the submit button of the form.

Now What I have observed, Google recaptcha verification expires ( with following message: "Verification expired. Check the checkbox again") during the upload process of big files and user is required to keep clicking on recaptcha after every few minutes until the file gets uploaded successfully.

Could you please help me to know how could I configure recaptcha so users don't have to keep clicking on the captcha while uploading files or any other alternative to ease this process.

Regards,
Tarun

Comment: No idea of how your tech stack is but you may want to control more stuff yourself. I particularly run PHP-powered sites and I store a server-side session variable with the date/time on which the user last completed a captcha. With this information, I don't display or require a new captcha again, until certain custom events happen (user has performed many actions, I consider enough time has passed, whatever). I don't even know how Google handles continuous captcha requests <:-)

Comment: We are using PHP. We have captcha only on the upload page. That would be first captcha a user will have to face. Users will face problems related to captcha verification failed. However I dont agree to your solution, Say I first manually upload file as real user and thereafter I schedule a bot.

Comment: You'd eventually hit the "performed many actions" part and get a new captcha (a captcha is designed to tell humans apart, not to prevent all kind of automation). From your follow-up, I understand the problem is that you verify the captcha result in your server-side upload script, which does not start running until upload completes, am I right?

Comment: Right, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Any suggestion please?

Comment: It's been several months since I last implemented reCaptcha and I can't remember the internals. If server-side validation is a must (I can't remember) you'll possibly need to inject an onsubmit handler that delays form submission until you get OK from server via AJAX. Sorry from being so vague but I'm not even in my regular computer today.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I did the same. Calling Ajax to verify recaptcha before submitting form. If the form gets submitted successfully, removing the captcha div off page so it does not show verification expired. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem, I did the following:
Calling Ajax to verify recaptcha before submitting the form. If the form gets submitted successfully, removing the captcha's div off page so it does not show verification expired.